# How to make Unity Launcher backlight use one colour?

Tags: unity, customization, colors

How to make Unity Launcher backlight use one colour? I want my launcher backlight all coloured with blue..

Comment: An excellent question. I'm sure any answers posted here will be useful to people trying to achieve a more consistent color scheme on their desktop.

Comment: This does not directly anser your question, but in [this OMG!Ubuntu! post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-customise-unity-like-never-before/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG%21+Ubuntu%21%29&utm_content=Google+Reader), they really do get their Unity launcher very blue.

Answer (score 3):

You will need the Gimp to do that.

First, we need to backup some launcher icons.

Open a terminal:

```
cd && mkdir launchericons
cd /usr/share/unity/4/
sudo cp launcher_icon_back_54.png launcher_icon_back_54.png.old
sudo cp launcher_icon_glow_62.png launcher_icon_glow_62.png.old
sudo cp launcher_icon_edge_54.png launcher_icon_edge_54.png.old
sudo cp launcher_icon_shine_54.png launcher_icon_shine_54.png.old
```

Now, we copy these 4 files to our newly created folder `launchericons`:

```
sudo cp launcher_icon_back_54.png launcher_icon_glow_62.png launcher_icon_edge_54.png  launcher_icon_shine_54.png ~/launchericons/
```

Ok. Files are backed up and copied to our home folder.
   If you haven't already done so, install the Gimp:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Start Gimp:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>gimp

Go to "File" -> "Open" . Open your folder "launchericons" and select the first png: launcher_icon_back_54.png .

Now, we have to choose the colour we want to use:

click on "Foreground & Background colors" (screenshot)[image]

Select the color you want (see the arrows, you can also use the eyedropper (circled) to select a blue anywhere on your desktop).
[image]

Make sure you write down somewhere the HTML notation of your selected color.

Now select in the Toolbox the "Bucket Fill Tool" and click in your launcher png in Gimp's main window (the little one):[image]

Save the changed png, and repeat the same process with the other 3 png's.

Then, copy all 4 files back to `/usr/share/unity/4/`:

```
sudo cp launcher_icon_back_54.png launcher_icon_glow_62.png launcher_icon_edge_54.png  launcher_icon_shine_54.png /usr/share/unity/4/
```

Logout and login back to unity and your backlights are now blue.

Comment: I attempted to try this on my Precise box, but the bucket tool doesn't seem to actually recolor the image. I'd have tried using the Colorize tool under Color instead anyway, but GIMP shows an error message saying "Colorize operates only on RGB color layers." Ideas on a workaround?

Comment: Found a solution: go to **Image > Mode** and select **RGB**. ([Source](http://androidforums.com/behold-2-all-things-root/73801-stealth-dial-pad-r10.html))

Comment: Also of note: by following this solution, GIMP will need root privileges in order to overwrite the launcher icon files when you save the changed versions. To do this, run `gksudo gimp` from Alt+F2 or a Terminal window.

Comment: ...okay, just tried it all out and it works (to some extent). I'm getting some of the icons as purplish, so I'm thinking there's still some color blending being done by Unity with the normal backlight color. Here's a [picture](http://imgur.com/Li3bV) of what I ended up with